# Calculated field on List View

Tags: list-view, calculated-column-formula

I've set up a Calculated field up on a view with the following formula:

=ID+800

At first it's fine. It shows incremental numbers (1001, 1002 etc) but after around two items are added or the view is refreshed it's just showing 800. If I go back into the settings and click on the formula it works again, but only for a short time. Very annoying! How can I get it to work permanently?

Answer (score 2):

As the ID field is not supported for calculated field, it will only update the data in your calculated column when the formula is updated.

if you want to work with the ID of a document then you'll have to use a workflow to extract the value of the id when the item is created and set your new value in a different field.